# Flutter SDK not found in Android Studio + MacOS

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio

Whenever i try to run my flutter app on Android Studio, this error message pop up:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/max/Projects/Flutter/myapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.
```

these are the first lines of said build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

I got it working on XCode.

The real problem is that i have installed flutter in that very folder, and i have 0 issue when i run `flutter doctor -v`.

After some googling i have found some answers but they were not useful because all of them had me verify
A - the flutter SDK path as per following image:
[image]

B - my myapp/android/local.properties file, which is as follows

```
sdk.dir=/Users/max/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/max/SDKs/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

C - my modules dependency
[image]

does anyone know what is going on? it's been 2 weeks and i haven't figured this out yet.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know if this would solve your issue: https://rohitksingh.medium.com/how-to-setup-flutter-in-android-studio-dae66020ea42 I have not used Flutter for long and made this blogpost when I first installed Flutter on my Android Studio. Let me know.

Comment: @RohitSingh tried your way, uninstalling and reinstalling plugins, setting the SDK path (which was set by default, the same way as image A in my question) but still not working, same errore.